# How to prompt user for String and swap order of words in the String in R

Tags: r, string, split, swap

I am new to R and have no idea how to complete this problem:

Using R. Create a program that prompts the user for his full name. Your code should swap the first name to last and last name to first and display the result.

Please help!

Comment: `nameprint=function(){
  name=readline(">What is your full name? ");
  cat("Your name is:",sub("(.*)\\s(.*)","\\2 \\1",name))
};
nameprint()
`

Comment: @Onyambu.. post your comment as answer whit a little information how the code works solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
nameprint=function(){ 
name=readline(">What is your full name? ")# prompts the user for his full name
reversed_name=sub("(.*)\\s(.*)","\\2 \\1",name)# Reverses the name
cat("Your name is:",reversed_name) #Prints the name
}
nameprint()
```